# Distance Between Two Nodes of Binary Search Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am new to Binary Tree Search Tree. Using recursion, i am finding the distance between two nodes of binary search Tree. If there is better approach .Please share your suggestion. It will help me to learn more.

```
 boolean found=false;

int distanceBetweenTwoNodeOfBST(Node node,int firstElement,int secondElement){

    if(firstElement==secondElement){
        return 0;
    }
    if(node==null){
        return 0;
    }else{
        if(node.element==firstElement || node.element==secondElement){
            int leftDis=distanceBetweenTwoNodeOfBST(node.left, firstElement, secondElement);
            int rightDis=distanceBetweenTwoNodeOfBST(node.right, firstElement, secondElement);

            if(leftDis>0 || rightDis>0){
                found=true;
            }

    if(leftDis> 0){
        --leftDis;
    }

    if(rightDis>0){
        --rightDis;
    }

            return 1+leftDis+rightDis;
        }

        int firstElementCount=distanceBetweenTwoNodeOfBST(node.left, firstElement, secondElement); // Going to left Subtree
        int secondELementCount=distanceBetweenTwoNodeOfBST(node.right, firstElement, secondElement); // Going to right Subtree
        if(firstElementCount>0 && secondELementCount>0){ // It means Least Common Ancestor is found
            found=true;
            return firstElementCount+secondELementCount;
        }else if(firstElementCount>0) {
            if(found){
                return firstElementCount;
            }else
            return firstElementCount+1;
        }else if(secondELementCount>0){
            if(found) return secondELementCount;
            else return secondELementCount+1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }

    }

}
```

Note -: If there is other better approach please share the suggestion. I am new to this.

Comment: You're more likely to have someone take your question seriously if you format your code in a reasonable way. The crazy indentation makes it very difficult to read.

Comment: It would also help if you could give a basic overview (in English) of how you are intending for your algorithm to work. That will help others understand your code.

Comment: Also, is your algorithm working as it is now?

Comment: Yes  setholopolus, its working fine.